# Rails 4 + Multiple Keys Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

With the deprecation of finder_sql and stuff it's been a pain working around to have a association with 2 keys.

Let's say that I have 2 models, `model_1` and `model_2`, both with their unique id, I want to make an association with 2 other fields, let's say each model share 2 other keys, like `category_id`and `country_id`.

Now I can do:

```
class Model_1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :model_2, -> (object) { where(category_id: object.category_id)}, foreign_key: :country_id, primary_key: :country_id
end
```

And now I can:

1. `m = Model1.find(x)`
2. `m.model_2`

This works!!, but ....

1. `m = Model1.includes(:model_2).find(x)`

This doesn't work, obviously because there is not `object` this way.
This results in `` NoMethodError: undefined method `category_id' for nil:NilClass ``.

Any one knows how to work around this in Rails 4.0+.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: On the right track with suggestion, this describes a composite key.

Comment: Diego, did some testing, and that gem modifies the default behavior of ```model.find(id)```, that's not acceptable for me, I already have my app in production and I NEED that functionality. Wurde, maybe composite key, or simple specified the finder or something.

Answer (score 0):

Am I reading right that you're wanting to a do join between Model 1 and Model 2 using two columns? Maybe `joins` would be more appropriate than a `where` call? I have no idea if this will work, but...

```
class Model_1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :model_2, -> {joins("model_2s ON model_1s.category_id = model_2s.category_id AND model_1s.country_id = model_2s.country_id")}
end
```

Comment: Hi James, joins is not a allowed option in for associations in Rails 4.